# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error while configuring MySQL Server 8.0

Tags: mysql

I am installing MySQL Server 8.0.29 from MySQL Installer, while applying configuration, I am getting error with writing configuration file :

```
Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file

Saving my.ini configuration file...
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file
```

How can I resolve this issue?
Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.
Uninstalled MySQL server, workbench with MySQL installer as well and reinstalled MySQL Installer 8.0.29 which is latest one(earlier I was using old version of this).
Using latest MySQL installer solved this issue!!